# Confusion in finding Period of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, periodic-functions

My instructor said this

> If $f$ has period $T_1$ and $g$ has period $T_2$, then $\frac{f}{g}$ has period which is least common multiple of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

But if I take $f=\sin(x)$ and $g = \cos(x)$ then above rule fails. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure he didn't say `has *a* period which...`? That would be correct, without implying that that would necessarily be the *minimal* period. (Otherwise put: $\tan x$ does in fact have "*a*" period of $2 \pi$, but it happens that the *minimal* one is half that, namely $\pi$.)

Comment: I don't know. I would like a explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dxiv said in the comments, the rule will only give a period, and not the minimal period of the function $f/g$. To take a trivial example, let $f=g=\sin(x),$ then $LCM(per(f),per(g))=2\pi,$ but $f/g = 1$ which has period $0.$